# Is there any particular advice on crank-bolt lubrication I should know?

Tags: lubrication, crank, crankshaft-pulley

I have a new crank-bolt to install following a timing-belt replacement.

Should I be lubricating this bolt? And if so, what kind of lube should I look for?

Answer (score 3):

No lubrication. Just ensure it is clean and dry (to include the threads on the crankshaft). This will get you the most accurate torque value.

Comment: Unless specified in the factory service manual, you should not use any lubricant as torque specs are usually generated assuming a "dry" fit.